# What is the opposite of an agent noun?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, agent-nouns

Is there a simple phrase to describe the object of an agent noun performing an action?

> The adviser helped the **advisee**.
>
> The employer fired the **employee**.

Is there a phrase similar to "agent noun" that can describe *advisee* and *employee*?

Comment: Why isn't this just part of your other question?

Comment: [Absolutive](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/88317/15299). But that also includes the subject of intransitive verbs.

Answer (score 1):

[Absolutive](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/88317/15299). But that also includes the subject of intransitive verbs.

> Adding the suffix *-ee* to a verb produces a label for a person who is the ***Absolutive*** of the verb – i.e, a person who is **either** the Direct Object of a Transitive verb, **or** the Subject of an Intransitive verb.